# Induced probability measure for argmax

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let us consider a metric space $S$ consisting of random functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R^+}$ and a probability measure $P$, defined on this space. Now suppose we define a new function $$\hat \theta=\mathop{\arg\max}_{\theta\in [0,1]}{ f}(\theta).$$

Then my interest is to find the induced probability measure in the new space of $\hat\theta$.

Could any one please help me in finding this probability measure?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Without knowing any further conditions on $S$ and $P$ there isn't much I can say beyond: $\hat{P}(\hat{\theta} > x) = P(\{ f | \hat{\theta} > x\})$.  If you had a specific density for $P$ you could compute that.

Comment: @muaddib Thanks for your attention. In my case the S is metric space and also have density for P, so I think your suggestion will help me.

Comment: @muaddib I got your your point but still unable to derive it. Suppose we know a specific density for $P$, then how to derive the  expression for $P(\{f|\hat\theta>x\})$?